# Determining percent habitat (raster data) present within buffer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I am worried this might be a basic question but I am new to ArcGIS.

I have a raster file of all the habitat distribution data for the region I am studying. I also have about 300 coordinate points. I am trying to determine the habitat present within 5 km of these points. However, I am having trouble doing this. I tried to convert my raster to a polygon and use an intersect my 5 km buffer but my output is always empty no matter what I try.

Is there something else I could try or something I am missing?

Comment: Are your point and polygon feature classes in the same coordinate system?  When you add them to a new map do they overlap each other?

Comment: yes they are the same coordinate system but the polygon layer is too large ArcMap says there is an error in drawing so I cant see the actual polygons

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] this question to focus on the actual error encountered. "I'm having trouble" isn't descriptive enough. You should certainly try to Repair Geometry on the faulty data file.

Comment: Do you have Spatial Analyst extension? If so you can try [Zonal Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm)

Comment: @BERA this is a very interesting suggestion thank you, since the data i am looking for are discrete qualitative values (wetland, forest etc) how do i select for this? i tried ALL statistic type but was unable to find the answer

Comment: I am able to determine the majority landuse but not the percentages of each land type

Comment: Try tabulate area tool.